# Show particular pages only if user logged in

Tags: php, drupal-7

I want particular pages i.e. this should be the user private pages to show when user logged in.

Comment: for that you have to set session

Comment: Session management in drupal https://www.drupal.org/node/597706

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can check via creating SESSION on login & checking at those page.

```
if(!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']=='admin')) {
   redirect('Your Login Pg');
}
```

In Drupal you have function **user_is_logged_in**. [Click Here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7.x)